# Count number of occurrences in column grouped by another column

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with multiple columns:

```
+-------------+--------+
|         x   |      y |
+-------------+--------+
|            a|     one| 
|            a|     one|
|            a|     two|
|            b|     one|
|            b|     two|  
|            c|     one| 
+-------------+--------+
```

I would like to group by `x` and for each group of `x` count the number of times "one" occurs.

something like:

```
df.groupBy(x).agg(countDistinct("one")).collect()
```

the output would be: 2, 1, 1 since "one" occurs twice for group `a` and once for groups `b` and `c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `filter` before `group by`

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

data = [("a", "one"),
        ("a", "one"),
        ("a", "two"),
        ("b", "one"),
        ("b", "two"),
        ("c", "one")]
# Create original df
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["x", "y"])

# Using filter before group_by
result_df = (df.filter(col('y') == 'one')
                .groupBy('x')
                .agg(count('*').alias('count_of_one')))

result_df.show()
# +---+------------+
# |  x|count_of_one|
# +---+------------+
# |  a|           2|
# |  b|           1|
# |  c|           1|
# +---+------------+
```

If you want to count with no matching value (0). You can use count with conditions like below

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

data = [("a", "one"),
        ("a", "one"),
        ("a", "two"),
        ("b", "one"),
        ("b", "two"),
        ("c", "one"),
        ("d", "three"),
        ("d", "four"),]

# Create original df
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["x", "y"])

# Using count with condition (when) ~ group by + having in SQL
# Note that you can't just use count(col("y") == "one") since count will skip null values
result_df = df.groupBy("x").agg(count(when(col("y") == "one", True)).alias("count_one"))

result_df.show()
# +---+---------+
# |  x|count_one|
# +---+---------+
# |  a|        2|
# |  b|        1|
# |  c|        1|
# |  d|        0|
# +---+---------+
```